# Prevent variable expansion in the parameter of a function

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

```
function kubeall { 
    for i in `seq 0 2`; do 
        echo pod-$i
        kubectl exec -it pod-$i -- bash -c "$@"
    done 
}
kubeall "cat ~/logs/pod-$i/log.out"
```

Is it possible to prevent expansion of the variable (`$i` in this case) in the parameter itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this what you want, but here it goes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
function kubeall {
    echo '$@: '"$@"
    for i in $(seq 0 0); do
        echo pod-$i
        #Note :: Include $i to the new shell.
        bash -c "i=$i; $@"
    done
}

#Note :: Using single quotes here to send the arguments as it is.
kubeall 'echo ~/pod-$i/log.out'
```

Output:

```
$@: echo ~/pod-$i/log.out
pod-0
/home/username/pod-0/log.out
```

Answer (score 4):

Passing `$i` to `kubeall` as-is won't help. You should pass `$i` to bash as a positional parameter instead.

```
function kubeall {
  for i in {0..2}; do
    echo "pod-$i"
    kubectl exec -it "pod-$i" -- bash -c "$1" bash "$i"
  done
}
```

```
kubeall 'cat ~/"logs/pod-$1/log.out"'
```

Comment: Works perfectly. A small comment for future viewers using kubectl, use `--` in `kubectl exec -it "pod-$i" -- bash -c "$1" bash "$i"`, else `-c` would be taken as a flag by kubectl.
Though I personally like the solution by @Darkman more as its more flexible. Thanks for this.